# Show All The Available Subcategory and Their Nested Subcategories in Menu in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, category, menu

[image]

I have done all the required settings but still it's not showing on the front end.

[image]

I am getting result like this. I want to show all the nested subcategory in the menu. Please help.

[image: I am getting the result like this]

Comment: It could be an issue with your custom theme. Try to change your theme to Luma to see if the categories shows correctly. Otherwise you probably tried it but just to make sure try to flush the caches and to do a reindexation.

Comment: I have checked with it, it's a Top Category Navigation=> Maximal Depth issues with the magento 2